# How to get the ElementRef of an element?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am loading a component using DCL loadnexttolocation. Is there a way I can load the component in a element specified. I mean I want to change the location where it loads by default. Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2dKxNAOgqYqGn4n0u8PT?p=preview

```
add() {
  this._dcl.loadNextToLocation(DynamicCmp, this._elementref);
}
```

Here is my code when I raise the event.. The elementref considers always root component. Is there a way I can find the elementref of children inside the root?

What I need is the component to be loaded inside this element:

```
<div #location id="location"></div>
```

Comment: No... What actually i need is i want the component to be loaded inside <my-app>....</my-app>    But it is loading next to <my-app>    I want to change the element ref...Is there any way that i can do?

Comment: I guess I got it. Please check my answer.

Comment: I think i am not successful again. can u generate a plunker demo which will be more helpful to go in the right way...Please

Comment: I added the link at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a template variable and query that element using `@ViewChild()`

```ts
@Component({selector: 'some-selector',
  template: `
  <div #location id="location"></div>      `
export class MyComponent {
  // only set after `ngAfterViewInit`
  @ViewChild('location') location;
  constructor(private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private _elementref: ElementRef) {}

  add() {
    this._dcl.loadNextToLocation(DynamicCmp, this.location);
  }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bjVZpf7tlE5iu4AyGQA9?p=preview)